# UITapGesture removing ability to select from UITableView when resigning keyboard responder

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I'm having an issue where I have added a UITapGestureRecognizer to resign first responder status of associated textfields so the keyboard will drop away.

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddMedViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func dismissKeyboard() {
    medNameText.resignFirstResponder()
    doseAmountText.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

This works fine for getting rid of the keyboard but not when I want to make a selection from a UITableView that is embedded in the same view. (The text fields are located outside this table view). 
Essentially each table view cell represents a pre created specific time that is chosen to match the text entered into the text fields then passed along all together to another view.

Any Idea how I can get the UITableView to still recognize the selection of cell when tapped while resigning first responder of the text fields?

I have tried adding a gestureRecognizer function but as I am new to Swift(and an amateur coder) I am not exaclty sure how it works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: try `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Comment: It's always so simple! Thank you very much!

Comment: I write it into answer so that if someone else can find it easily. Feel free to accept and vote. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

It means **touches are delivered to a view when a gesture is recognized.**